# Shiny Apps exits with code 137, No issue in Logs

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I am trying to deploy a simple shiny app for the course I'm doing on data science, but I keep on getting this error:

> The application failed to start (exited with code 137).

I have already minimized the size of my app by not installing any other package aside from `shiny`. My data is saved in RDS format, and I just rewrote the functions I used for the server. The UI is relatively lean as well, the image is sourced online.

I checked other answers to this question, but all of them say that it's a memory error. There is no evidence in my logs that it is a memory error. I have also set my limit to 1GB in shinyapps.io. All my files are 208 mb in total, so I don't understand why it would consume the entire 1 gb when uploaded.

Here is my app.R code for your reference (excuse the messy functions, I'm still starting out and using all base functions was hard for me to do)

```
# algo and ngrams
quintgrams_df <- readRDS("quintgrams.rds")
quadgrams_df <- readRDS("quadgrams.rds")
trigrams_df <- readRDS("trigrams.rds")
bigrams_df <- readRDS("bigrams.rds")

getResultDF <- getResultDF <- function(input, base, n){
  input <- tolower(input)
  input <- gsub('[[:punct:] ]+',' ',input)
  input <- gsub('[[:digit:]]+', '', input)
  input <- words(input)
  searchterm <- paste0("^", paste0(input[
    ifelse(length(input) < n, 0, length(input)-n+1):
      length(input)], 
    collapse = " ")
    )
  result_df <- base[grep(searchterm, base$ngram),]
  result_df <- result_df[order(-result_df$freq),]
  return(result_df)
}

getNextWord <- function(input) {
  resultdf <- getResultDF(input, quintgrams_df, 4)
  if (nrow(resultdf) > 0) {
    ## result is the first row, ngram
    prediction <- resultdf
  } else if (nrow(resultdf) == 0) {
    resultdf <- getResultDF(input, quadgrams_df, 3)
    if (nrow(resultdf) > 0) {
      ## result is the first row, ngram
      prediction <- resultdf
    } else if (nrow(resultdf) == 0) {
      resultdf <- getResultDF(input, trigrams_df, 2)
      if (nrow(resultdf) > 0) {
        prediction <- resultdf
      } else if (nrow(resultdf) == 0) {
        resultdf <- getResultDF(input, bigrams_df, 1)
        if (nrow(resultdf) > 0) {
          prediction <- resultdf
        } else {prediction <- rbind(resultdf, data.frame(ngram = "nopred", freq = " "))}
      }
    }
  }
  if (nrow(prediction) >= 3) {
    x <- prediction[1:3,1]
  } else {x <- prediction[,1]}
  return(x)
}

library(shiny)
library(tm)


ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 10,
           tags$style(HTML(".tabbable > .nav > li > a {background-color:Thistle; color: white;font-weight:normal; border-radius:25px}
                           .tabbable > .nav > li[class = active] > a {background-color:Indigo; color: white; font-weight:bold; border-radius:25px}"
           )
           ),
           div(style = "float:right; margin-right:45vh; margin-top:5vh;",
               tabsetPanel(type = "pills",
                           tabPanel("Talk to Me",
                                    div(style = 
                                          "margin-top:10px; margin-left:12px; padding:10px;
                                        height:75vh; width:100vh; background-color:Thistle; color: Indigo;
                                        border-radius: 25px;",
                                        div(h3("Say What?! is an app that predicts your next word", 
                                               style = "margin-top:20px"),
                                            textInput(inputId = "text", label = "", value = "", 
                                                      width = "100%", placeholder = "Say something!"),
                                            style = "display:block; margin-left:20px; margin-right:20px"),
                                        div(style = "padding:20px; color:Indigo; font-size:25px",
                                            textOutput(outputId = "textmimic")),
                                        div(style = "padding:20px; color:Indigo; font-size:20px",
                                            h3("or did you mean..."),
                                            textOutput(outputId = "predictions"))
                                    )
           ),
           tabPanel("About the Algorithm",
                    div(style = 
                          "margin-top:10px; margin-left:12px; padding:10px;
                                 height:75vh; width:100vh; background-color:Thistle; color: Indigo;
                                 border-radius: 25px;",
                        h3("Katz Back Off"),
                        p("The Katz Back-Off model is a generative model based on historical ngrams. From the train data, different quint-, quad-, tri-, and bigrams were created from which the inputted text will be compared to. The output is based on the conditional probability of a word, given it's previous words based on the ngram histories. It is called a 'back off' model as it backs off on searching from the longer history ngram (e.g. quintgrams) to the shorter history ngram (e.g. quint- to quadgrams) should the pattern of the text not be found in the former."),
                        h3("Base Data"),
                        p("Base data was gotten from a database of ENGLISH texts collected from various twitter feeds, blogs, and news online. Total population data amounts to more than 4 million, and a sample of 10% per text source was used as train data set. To ensure efficiency and effectiveness of the model, the text was converted to ASCII, punctuations--both isolated and within words-- were removed, as well as any URLs, numbers, and symbols."),
                        h3("Future Improvements"),
                        p("At present, the model is slow to work because of the many loops. A more robust function should be created to ensure that the loops implemented are less, therefore taking less time. A dynamic training database should also be created to ensure effectiveness of the model. Because of the 10% sample, not all words are predicted. A continuous and partial observation set will improve the performance of the model.")
                    )
           )
           ))
           ),
    column(width = 2,
           div(style = "float:right; background-color:transparent",
               img(src = "https://i.ibb.co/K9DCZwY/logo.png")
           )
    )
)
  )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$predictions <- reactive({
    predicted <- getNextWord(input$text)
    predicted[1]
  })
})
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Hoping to see if there are any other reasons as to why the `code 137` error would come up. Thanks in advance!

update: I was able to reduce entire app folder to 104 mb, it's still not working. Attaching full deployment log here for reference.

```
    ----- Deployment log started at  2019-08-16 22:12:12  -----
Deploy command: 
 rsconnect::deployApp(appDir = "~/Coursera Files/11 Capstone/CAPSTONEFINAL",      appFileManifest = "C:/Users/10012188/AppData/Local/Temp/7aa4-d28c-b0f6-d5ff",      account = "lasmyr", server = "shinyapps.io", appName = "CAPSTONEFINAL",      appTitle = "CAPSTONEFINAL", launch.browser = function(url) {         message("Deployment completed: ", url)     }, lint = FALSE, metadata = list(asMultiple = FALSE, asStatic = FALSE),      logLevel = "verbose") 

Session information: 
R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17134)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.2   rsconnect_0.8.13
Cookies: 
[1] "None"
GET /v1/applications/?filter=account_id:288704&filter=name:CAPSTONEFINAL&count=100&offset=0 1310ms
POST /v1/applications/ 1280ms
<< {
  "name": "CAPSTONEFINAL",
  "template": "shiny",
  "account": 288704
}
----- Bundle upload started at  2019-08-16 22:12:15  -----
[2019-08-16 22:12:15] Inferring App mode and parameters 
[2019-08-16 22:12:15] Bundling app dir 
[2019-08-16 22:12:17] Generate manifest.json 
[2019-08-16 22:12:22] Writing Rmd index if necessary 
[2019-08-16 22:12:22] Compressing the bundle 
POST /v1/bundles 1339ms
<< {
  "application": 1091111,
  "content_type": "application/x-tar",
  "content_length": 109193845,
  "checksum": "46826ac1f89e8ff7458d3c04ec30bf9f"
}
[2019-08-16 22:12:31] Starting upload now 
PUT /bundles/application-1091111/715689d56ccc406f9874a9c0f55d653d.tar.gz?AWSAccessKeyId=ASIA54P7SCTK26XEE76L&x-amz-acl=bucket-owner-full-control&Expires=1565968350&content-md5=RoJqwfiej%2FdFjTwE7DC%2Fnw%3D%3D&x-amz-security-token=AgoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEKr%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIGmd6pEcrfROfVxIB2LVTkzF13%2FPD86O90h6UtcWzNkpAiEA%2BUOZ8Mw863fCieds3DslfHiOV6DBCj1TJ0Un1s%2Ba858q2gMIQhAAGgw5NTQ1NTU1NjkzNjUiDL8s7lMR6E4zstxkACq3A6IA6BWpLOD7T%2BbHN8F0pX0sCJv6norJGmvPGXdDPzdU18mMlVPwinD%2B3l4eXTCIJwYQQbc04LJ49VdPTmytnu1IFiEDSIRcieF3YajVgZfT%2BCqzwTuedgeIT9uxCAfgBJpH5h4gXxhLfbXuK%2BDbdYoz2D91StiZIFAjCmg7Y%2BXBrWURbdVWkKtcgfDAp6FlTwYMbIEI%2BImoZEb3VbuekFH3FlSiaFnhaa1cesSeLfZrlm%2BM0Q7ZExgpDxeskpt2zjGH37F%2Biqk3%2Fi1OAvDqxFoRVtptNLCTtYbuyJ%2BDlez%2B9DX4KK%2FtOo4e97drNes4u0m0C74DKsI3LQIwoThQoZ0o54iSwd1MhacOPavBQ0C%2BE18HbcQdPvt5ZyaHHy1yljV%2BOkj2BR9%2FikfIiLbl5LXMiPrfBlWQUthNX2Q0%2BbwlUO07FmXC5jVbtysbjamv5SOri%2BBqfrbfPC5cFC0m%2BwzExqcmw6SPEJ%2FWwd9thXqL5WH%2FVv%2BZYu88hE86jipgKSWk2QOiWNZ2b7uPLiscHVBL8K2rgkVtXukLYweWQB0icXXTbRvpEbTNIBVwkYrYHSO4bWqtYssw5OfZ6gU6tAGjSzEW2PJXqKbzV%2B8ZH%2B0yvDVXaBa4qQddhW%2BRmM7BuwIX5toCqnAdK%2BLQ2huvllrdlZCD3jgpjT5DkGWfUddkwLTUsTrMXk3H%2FFKMQY6Hj7RuNz55h78rXyqdFfwj9sKZ%2Fa2iUfuJFUSYW23gbCqCYDL9w66bj9SYoDjqHx61UI%2BvMw4pUOHd9giJpKu8qAIOsPXRwtZ2XTeuM0FZ95y47tRx%2BLsnZQsZLGsSH6g3P5YdJgs%3D&Signature=KgPfzrQIVj67zqaLSOMKuU0MgXQ%3D&content-type=application%2Fx-tar 422680ms
[2019-08-16 22:19:33] Upload complete 
POST /v1/bundles/2326111/status 1500ms
<< {
  "status": "ready"
}
GET /v1/bundles/2326111 1230ms
[2019-08-16 22:19:36] Saving deployment record for CAPSTONEFINAL -  
----- Server deployment started at  2019-08-16 22:19:36  -----
POST /v1/applications/1091111/deploy 1290ms
<< {
  "bundle": 2326111
}
Waiting for task: 639230448
GET /v1/tasks/639230448 1230ms
  building: Processing bundle: 2326111
GET /v1/tasks/639230448 1189ms
  building: Building image: 2466334
GET /v1/tasks/639230448 1310ms
  building: Installing system dependencies
GET /v1/tasks/639230448 1200ms
  building: Fetching packages
GET /v1/tasks/639230448 1199ms
  building: Installing packages
GET /v1/tasks/639230448 1189ms
GET /v1/tasks/639230448 1280ms
GET /v1/tasks/639230448 1389ms
GET /v1/tasks/639230448 1240ms
GET /v1/tasks/639230448 1350ms
GET /v1/tasks/639230448 1250ms
  building: Installing files
GET /v1/tasks/639230448 1360ms
GET /v1/tasks/639230448 1230ms
  building: Pushing image: 2466334
GET /v1/tasks/639230448 1259ms
GET /v1/tasks/639230448 1219ms
GET /v1/tasks/639230448 1329ms
GET /v1/tasks/639230448 1170ms
GET /v1/tasks/639230448 1189ms
GET /v1/tasks/639230448 1350ms
GET /v1/tasks/639230448 1290ms
GET /v1/tasks/639230448 1239ms
GET /v1/tasks/639230448 1240ms
GET /v1/tasks/639230448 1189ms
GET /v1/tasks/639230448 1250ms
GET /v1/tasks/639230448 1340ms
  deploying: Starting instances
GET /v1/tasks/639230448 1329ms
  rollforward: Activating new instances
GET /v1/tasks/639230448 1250ms
  success: Stopping old instances
----- Deployment log finished at  2019-08-16 22:20:39  -----
Deployment completed: https://lasmyr.shinyapps.io/CAPSTONEFINAL/
```

Comment: Have you tested the memory issue by trimming the n-gram model?

Comment: Good idea! I didn't trim the ngrams at first to make sure the model it more accurate, but I just tried it and it's the same accuracy and I finally got it to upload! Thanks a bunch!